# Continuity of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I need some help with the following problem

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a linear map such that $T^2=T$. If the kernel of $T$ and the range of $T$ are closed, prove that $T$ is continuous.

I tried to mimic the proof of the similar theorem for linear functionals (which only needs the kernel to be closed) but I fail to produce a sequence in the kernel the same way. Specifically, in that theorem at some point a sequence $a-v_nTa$  in the kernel of $T$ is created for some $a\not\in \ker T$, but in this case I can't seem to construct such a sequence (since $Ta$ won't be a number for me).

Comment: Have to tried to show that $T$ is closed?

Comment: @T.A.E. To use the closed graph theorem to prove continuity you mean? I thought about it too but I couldn't prove it. Any hints on how to do it?

Comment: Start by assuming $\{ x_{n} \}$ and $\{ Tx_{n} \}$ converge to $x$ and $y$, respectively. Then you must show that $Tx=y$. You have $x_{n}=(I-T)x_{n}+Tx_{n}$, and all three must converge. $(I-T)x_{n}$ is in the kernel of $T$ and $Tx_{n}$ is in the range. So $x=(x-y)+y$ with $x-y\in ...$ and $y\in ...$.

Comment: @T.A.E. with $x-y\in \ker T$ and $y\in R(T)$. Then I have $Tx=T(x-y)+Ty$ and since $T(x-y)=0$ I get $Tx=Ty$. But since $y\in R(T)$, there exists a $w$ such that $y=Tw$ and thus $Ty=T(Tw)=T^2w=Tw=y$. So $Ty=y$ and I have $Tx=y$ as required. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer guided by T.A.E.'s comment.

Let $\{x_n\}$, $\{Tx_n\}$ converge to $x$ and $y$, respectively. We can write 
$$x_n=(I-T)x_n+Tx_n$$
and all three must converge. Since 
$$T(I-T)x_n=Tx_n-T^2x_n=Tx_n-Tx_n=0$$
we have $(I-T)x_n\in \ker T$. Moreover, $Tx_n\in R(T)$. So by taking the limit
$$x=(x-y)+y$$
and $x-y\in \ker(T)$, $y\in R(T)$ because both the kernel and the range of $T$ are closed. Therefore
$$Tx=T(x-y)+Ty=0+Ty=Ty$$
but since $y\in R(T)$, $y=Tw$ for some $w\in X$. Thus $Ty=T(Tw)=T^2w=Tw=y$. So $Ty=y$ which proves $Tx=y$ and therefore $T$ is closed. By the closed graph theorem, $T$ is continuous.